# Qt: Path to data directory

Tags: c++, qt

I have a Qt application with a large amount of data stored in a folder called "Data", which lies in the same directory as the applications qrc file.

I want to somehow have the application know where to find this folder. I don't want to add all of the data as resource files because I want to be able to add and remove new data files into the Data directory without having to recompile every time. I don't want to hardcode relative file paths because the execution directory can differ depending on operating system, how the application is launched etc, and I don't want to hardcode absolute directories because they won't be the same if the application is compiled on different machines.

How can I make my application know where to look for the data folder? The directory structure of the entire project will be the same regardless of what OS/machine it is on.

Comment: In a typical installation, where is this data folder located? Have you looked into QDesktopServices' `storageLocation` method?

Answer (score 3):

The application directory is available through [QCoreApplication.applicationDirPath()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#applicationDirPath), available via the global `qApp`:

```
  #include <QApplication>

  ...
  QString appDir = qApp.applicationDirPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a xml config file that would contain the list of all possible combinations of OS application and the corresponding path to read.

At startup read the config file and check the os version and other configuration to decide which path to use from the xml file read